# Equivalent definitions for measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $E$ be any set of real numbers. Then the following four assertion is
> equivalent to the measurability of $E$. For each $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an open set $O $ containing $E$ for which $m^* (O \setminus E) < \varepsilon$.

I'm wondering how to digest the statement here. Is it so that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is a single open set $O$ that satisfies $m^*(O \setminus E) < \varepsilon$?

If so could the statement be reformulated as

> For any $n \in \Bbb N$ there exists open $O_n $ containing $E$ for which $m^*(O_n \setminus E) < \frac1n$.

What's not clear to me is that in the first formulation there could be uncountably many $O$'s corresponind to different epsilons. Perhaps even uncountable many corresponding to single epsilon?

In the latter one we have only singular $O_n$ corresponding to a particular choice for $n$. And only countable many $O_n$'s in total.

How should I interpret this?

Comment: "there exists" does not mean "there exists only one". There could be many (infinitely many, uncountably many) possible choices of $O_n$ - you just are only guaranteed one. In extreme cases many of the $O_n$s may even coincide - meaning you cannot conclude that there are infinitely many either.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both those definitions are equivalent.

You are correct that using the second formulation, you only need to find countably many open sets: one per $n\in\mathbb{N}$. While to do the first you need an open set for each positive $\epsilon\in \mathbb{R}$. However, given you can do this for a set $E$, it doesn't tell you *how many $O$s work for a given $\epsilon$ or a given $n$*, so there is no contradiction.

Similarly, a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$ iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $|a_n - a|<\epsilon$. However, this is equivalent to saying that for every $\frac{1}{m}>0$ there is $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $|a_n - a|<\frac{1}{m}$.

There isn't anything special about measure here: for many limiting processes you can replace "arbitrarily small positive $\epsilon$" with "arbitrarily small $\frac{1}{n}$" because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.